# Interests of having 2 SP2013 server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation, farm

I'm currently working with 3 servers in dev env. The objective is to replace the current all-in-one SP server.

This is what I planned :

- One for SQL Database (because SQL uses a lot of RAM)
- One for SharePoint 2013 hosting Central Admin, and my intranet
  website
- One for SharePoint 2013 hosting my extranet website.

Does that take any sense for you ?

I mean : I thought that if I put 2 SP servers in a farm, I could use server1 for intranet with AD auth, and server 2 for extranet with FBA SQL Auth. I thought that its better to separate SQL Auth and AD Auth, same for intranet/extranet...

I set up a dev env, and when I create a web application, I cannot choose on which server it will be hosted, because I didn't understand that 2 SP servers (if i'm right) are hosting the iis site, and if 1 break, the site still up.

Can someone help me understand what I really need ? I mean, separate AD Auth/SQL Auth for security reasons are the good reasons ? Same for intranet/extranet ?

Feel free to ask for more details obviously.

EDIT : to clarify, the question is : What would you advice me to do, knowing that I need both extranet/intranet, with different Auth (SQL FBA for extranet & AD for intranet).

Answer (score 1):

You can have both type of authentication on one WFE. Authnetication is basically for Web Application scope not the server scoped. I would Like to know how many user will access the SharePoint for both apps?

When you create a web application during that process you will see the Public Url option, which is typically server name & port number( server name is always Central Admin), you will change it and point to other server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806885(v%3Doffice.15).aspx

I would create both web application on one server and keep all the services application i.e UPA, Search on Central Admin server.

Comment: I'm talking about 100/300 users, and at the same time, about 50/75 users. So you recommend, 2 SP server (1 for CentralAdmin, 1 for my two webapp) and 1 sql server. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Total number of user not more than 500 as per your details.I am positve you will not have any issue. check this stream line diagram...http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37000

Comment: thank you for your help/answer. Do you have any best practises about hosting 2 web app on the same sp server, where 1 is intranet and the other is extranet ? In terms of https, publishing (ARR ?), Authentication (AD & FBA SQL) etc. ?

Comment: You can create 20 Web Apps per farm But maximum app pool for a server should be 10. this is upper limit set by MSFT. in your case you have 2 web app and if both run under there own app pools still you will be well under limit...for more limits check this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#WebserverAppServer

Comment: Yes, every web app I'll create will have its own app pool. Maximum web apps I'll create is 3, so no problem for limits. Thanks for precision.

Comment: Yes, you will be fine

Comment: The thing that really scares me is, coexistence between 2 web apps, with different Auth (SQL/AD) and for different users (intra/extra net) ...

Comment: still no problem, because both web apps works independently and authentication method is for each web app. we have mix authentication for web apps in our farm since 2009 and no issue....more over we have one web app with multiple Authentications...every web app have their own set of resources i.e app pool, web.config, IIS site etc

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, makes me confident for this project. Last little question (I swear !), for publishing webapp over internet, would you use ARR ? or WAP (+ADFS) ? or something else ?

Comment: we use ADFS and in some web apps FBA